# Is this the correct way to structure this SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently working with PHP and SQL on a website. There is a database containing users (accounts), organisations, and a relational table to link organisations to accounts (a many to many relationship)

When I delete an account from the database, the SQL query should also delete any organisations the account is linked to if the account being deleted is the only account linked to an organisation.

I am relatively new to SQL and have constructed a query which should delete an organisation from the organisations table under the conditions described above.
Here is my query:

```
'DELETE FROM TBL_ORGANISATIONS WHERE id = (
    SELECT org_id FROM TBL_AFFILIATIONS WHERE account_email = :email AND (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TBL_AFFILIATIONS WHERE org_id IN (
            SELECT org_id FROM TBL_AFFILIATIONS WHERE account_email = :email
        )
    ) = 1
)'
```

Is this the correct way to structure this query or is there a clearer / more efficient way to do this? As I previously mentioned I am fairly new to SQL and have not yet grasped the concept of all the SQL keywords which can be useful in constructing queries such as this (JOIN etc.)

I thank you all in advance for any advice you can provide.

By the way:
I am using PDO hence the :email for those of you wondering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have [foreign key constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key), like I think you should, then this statement will fail, because the affiliation record still points to the organisation record to be deleted.

You can use `ON DELETE CASCADE` to delete the organisation, like Mihai suggested in his (now deleted) comment, but to do that, you will still have to check whether there's only one affiliation linked to the organisation.

In this case, I'd rather query the organisation's ID first. You will probably have that at hand anyway, because you'll know the details of the account you are deleting. Then first delete the account and next delete the organisation if you need to, with a statement that looks like this:

```
DELETE FROM TBL_ORGANISATIONS o
WHERE 
  o.id = :ThatIdYouQueriedBefore AND
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM TBL_AFFILIATIONS a.org_id = o.id);
```

Personally I'm not a big fan of cascaded deletes, since a seemingly small mistake might cost you a lot of data, but even you do use them, I don't think it makes this particular case much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would do two logical queries.  Feel free to wrap in transaction if you need to guarantee that the deletes always happen together, with a rollback if they don't.

First, delete both the account and the account to organization affiliation with a single query (here I am assuming your account table name)

```
DELETE tbl_account,tbl_affiliations
FROM tbl_account INNER JOIN tbl_affiliations
   ON tbl_account.account_email = tbl_affiliations.account_email /* I am assuming join condition here, perhaps there is an id to be used instead */
WHERE tbl_account.acount_email = ?
```

Then, delete any orphaned organizations:

```
DELETE tbl_organizations
FROM tbl_organizations LEFT JOIN tbl_affiliations
  ON tbl_organizations.org_id = tbl_affiliations.org_id
WHERE tbl_affiliations.org_id IS NULL
```

Note that since that last query is not dependent on any account-specific information, you could also consider running an asynchronous process to clean up orphaned organizations if you don't need the organization deletion to happen synchronously with the account deletion.

The benefit of this approach is that you can potentially always delete user accounts in the same way, using the first query, as this works regardless as to whether there are multiple accounts associated with the organization.  So you don't need any extra application logic or SQL SELECT subqueries to look for cases where there is a single account associated with an organization.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I am now using foreign key constraints i think this may not work due to the relationship between the organisation table and affiliations table. However, if I had not added the foreign keys, this seems like a good solution, so thanks.

I would upvote you but I can't as I do not yet have 15 reputation

Comment: @BenGuest Well, you really shouldn't have a foreign key constraint between the organizations table and the affiliations table with the way you are using it.  I personally am not a fan of foreign key constraints anyway, as IMO this sort of logic should be implemented at the application layer when possible (and reasonable from a performance standpoint).  That being said, you could turn off foreign key constraints for the duration of the queries.

Comment: Im not sure I understand why it is not a good idea to use them. Having foreign keys allows the affiliations table to automatically update if say an account email address changes (this is the primary key in the account table). I guess I could do this in a separate query from PHP, but I can let the database engine handle this for me. Do you mean that having foreign keys may make a query to fulfil the operation in the question more difficult to create / more dangerous to other data in the database (i.e. more likely to accidentally delete other data)?

Comment: @BenGuest I guess my preference is always to handle application logic in the application layer.  You will find that you can typically write a query to update rows across multiple tables simultaneously. That way you don't have logic spread across two places. Logic that may be hidden from developers touching the application down the line.  Explicitly defining the interactions between tables in the application logic makes the behavior clear to anyone who may be working with the code.

Comment: @BenGuey My note about the foreign key relationship being a problem in the case of the organization to affiliation relationship stems for your use case that you actually have conditional behavior you are trying to achieve.  You only want to delete rows on the organization table in certain cases. Foreign keys have no way of operating conditionally like that.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to delete the data from two tables at a time, you can try this.

```
DELETE from TBL_ORGANISATIONS TO JOIN TBL_AFFILIATIONS TA 
    ON(TO.id=TA.org_id) where TA.account_email=:email;
```

Here, we are trying to delete the rows from two tables TBL_ORGANISATIONS and TBL_AFFILIATIONS using primary key of TO(i.e. id) and foriegn key TA(i.e. org_id) and adding a condition using where clause where TA.account_email=:email.

Comment: Well, I am really trying to delete data from 3 tables: Delete the row from accounts table where email = account_to_delete's_email, delete all rows from affiliations table where account_email = account_to_delete's_email, and finally, delete row from organisations table where organisation does not have any references in affiliations table